# How to calculate the tree the results by combining individual leaf paths?

Tags: r, algorithm, shell, data-structures, tree

Let's say I have an input file where each line contains the path from the root (A) to a leaf

```
echo "A\tB\tC\nA\tB\tD\nA\tE" > lines.txt
A   B   C
A   B   D
A   E
```

How can I easily generate the resulting tree?: `(A(B(C,D),E))`

I'd like to use GNU tools (awk, sed, etc.) because they tend to work better with large files, but an R script would also work. The R input would be:

```
# lines <- lapply(readLines("lines.txt"), strsplit, " +")
lines <- list(list(c("A", "B", "C")), list(c("A", "B", "D")), list(c("A","E")))
```

Comment: R *is* a "GNU tool" :) If you want to do with awk or sed, what would be the output? It seems to me you want the output as a list in R in any case, no?

Comment: Sort the list and then take the largest prefix of two consecutive lines. The postfix of the second line is new.

Comment: I would use perl hashes. You use the path parts to walk down the hash tree. When finished you enclose the sub keys of an element in brackets, et voila. Python will have a similar concept.

Comment: @janos a string would work

Comment: @Coroos I'm not sure I have understood your approach, could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, see the shell script below: You sort the lines, and then compare the two lines. Now, you actually have to take care of the postfix that was removed in the new line, and the postfix that was added. So the script is a lot more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @Coroos wow, that's crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

my $t = {};
while (<>) {
    my @a = split;
    my $t1 = $t;
    while (my $a = shift @a) {
        $t1->{$a} = {} if not exists $t1->{$a};
        $t1 = $t1->{$a};
    }
}

print &p($t)."\n";

sub p {
    my ($t) = @_;
    return
    unless keys %$t;

    return '('
        . join(',', map { $_ . p($t->{$_}) } sort keys %$t)
        . ')';
}
```

This script returns:

```
% cat <<EOF | perl l.pl
A   B   C
A   B   D
A   E
EOF
(A(B(C,D),E))
```

Note that this script, due to recursion in p is not at all suited for large datasets. But that can be easily resolved by turning that into a double for loop, like in the first while above.

Answer (score 1):

Why do it the easy way, if you can use Bourne Shell script instead? Note, this is not even Bash, this is plain old Bourne shell, without arrays...

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# A B C
# A B D
# A E
#
# "" vs "A B C"         -> 0->3, ident 0        -> -0+3 -> "(A(B(C"
# "A B C" vs "A B D"    -> 3->3, ident 2        -> -1+1 -> ",D"
# "A B D" vs "A E"      -> 3->2, ident 1        -> -2+1 -> "),E"
# "A E" vs. endc        -> 2->0, ident 0        -> -2+0 -> "))"
#
# Result: (A(B(C,D),E))
#
# Input stream is a path per line, path segments separated with spaces.

process_line () {
    local line2="$@"
    n2=$#
    set -- $line1
    n1=$#

    s=
    if [ $n2 = 0 ]; then                # last line (empty)
        for s1 in $line1; do
            s="$s)"
        done
    else
        sep=
        remainder=false

        for s2 in $line2; do
            if ! $remainder; then
                if [ "$1" != $s2 ]; then
                    remainder=true
                    if [ $# = 0 ]; then # only children
                        sep='('
                    else                # sibling to an existing element
                        sep=,
                        shift
                        for s1 in $@; do
                            s="$s)"
                        done
                    fi
                fi
            fi

            if $remainder; then         # Process remainder as mismatch
                s="$s$sep$s2"
                sep='('
            fi

            shift                       # remove the first element of line1
        done
    fi

    result="$result$s"
}

result=
line1=
(
    cat - \
    | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]\+/ /' \
    | sed -e '/^$/d' \
    | sort -u
    echo ''                             # last line marker
) | while read line2; do
        process_line $line2
        line1="$line2"


        test -n "$line2" \
            || echo $result
    done
```

This produces the correct answer for two different files (`l.sh` is the shell version, `l.pl` the version in Perl):

```
% for i in l l1; do cat $i; ./l.sh < $i; ./l.pl < $i; echo; done
A
A B
A B C D
A B E F
A G H
A G H I
(A(B(C(D),E(F)),G(H(I))))
(A(B(C(D),E(F)),G(H(I))))

A B C
A B D
A E
(A(B(C,D),E))
(A(B(C,D),E))
```

Hoohah!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I got it:

```
# input
lines <- c(list(c("A", "B", "C")), list(c("A", "B", "D")), list(c("A","E")))

# generate children
generate_children <- function(lines){
    children <- list()
    for (line in lines) {
        for (index in 1:(length(line)-1)){
            parent <- line[index]
            next_child <- line[index + 1]
            if (is.null(children[[parent]])){
                children[[parent]] <- next_child
            } else {
                if (next_child %notin% children[[parent]]){
                    children[[parent]] <- c(children[[parent]], next_child)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    children
}

expand_children <- function(current_parent, children){
    if (current_parent %in% names(children)){
        expanded_children <- sapply(children[[current_parent]], function(current_child){
            expand_children(current_child, children)
        }, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
        output <- setNames(list(expanded_children), current_parent)
    } else {
        output <- current_parent
    }
    output
}

children <- generate_children(lines)
root <- names(children)[1]
tree <- expand_children(root, children)
dput(tree)
# structure(list(A = structure(list(B = c("C", "D"), "E"), .Names = c("B",""))), .Names = "A")
```

Is there a simpler answer?